# Spotlight/Search on Fedora

Tags: fedora, software-rec, search

I apologize for the MacOSX reference, but is there an equivalent of Spotlight-Search in Fedora, specifically FC14 x86_64 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few releases ago, there was a big push for something called Beagle, which is a "personal space" search tool. I'm not quite sure why that push [died out](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/dashboard-hackers/2010-January/msg00001.html), but the package is still part of Fedora and you can install it with `yum install beagle-gnome` if you are a Gnome user or `yum install kerry` for the KDE front-end. There are also optional `beagle-firefox`, `beagle-thunderbird`, and `beagle-evolution` packages which cause those programs' data to be indexed.

There's a number of full-text indexers / search engines available for Fedora as well, like [Namazu](http://www.namazu.org/), [Xapian](http://xapian.org/), [Strigi](http://www.vandenoever.info/software/strigi/), and [Pinot](https://code.google.com/p/pinot-search/), but as far as I can see, Beagle had  the greatest ambition of being an integrated part of everyone's desktop environment, with a slick UI and everything. Namazu and Xapian are mainly focused on the backend, not the user experience. Strigi also seems to be a dead project. And Pinot looks promising but also appears to be one of those one-guy projects where the developer's continuing interest in the project may be a concern.

Edit: Missed a big one! There's also [Tracker](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker) — `yum install tracker-search-tool`. This seems to be under active development as part of the Gnome project, which is very promising. While it's designed to be desktop-environment-neutral, I'm not finding a current KDE front-end.

So, there you go. Depending on how satisfying that is, the answer to your question is either "yes" or "no". :)

Comment: I am fine with Strigi. Would I be correct in assuming that to search for a file of the name ABC_XYZ.cpp, I'd have to open a Dolphin window and use the search in that ? As in there is no quick shortcut for the same ?

Comment: @Humble Debugger — Strigi has a plugin interface, so all sorts of lightweight clients are possible, and in theory you could find one and attach that to a keyboard shortcut. Except, I don't know of any clients that anyone actually ever implemented.

Answer (score 1):

krunner, does a nice job in KDE. The ubuntu unity search bar is definitely the closest thing on linux to spotlight though...